# How to write a loop with an "or" condition

Tags: while-loop, conditional-operator

What would be the best way to write this statement in Java.

continue loop while either x or y equals true

I have tried these and they fail. I am not sure of the proper way to construct this statement.

while (x || y == true)

while (x | y == true)

while (y == true) || (x == true)

while (y == true) | (x == true)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which language? Most follow the `While(x == true || y == true)` syntax

Comment: Or more succinctly `while (x || y)`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth true, but if perhaps he was testing if `x == 5` the original example might be more helpful :)

Comment: @Nerves82 In Java `while (x || y)`.

Comment: By the way @OliCharlesworth, your name is amazing. Just thought you ought to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while( x == true || y == true ){   
    //do loopy stuff
}
```

This may be different for some languages, but for C based syntax languages, this should work

Comment: It's redundant to write `== true` in conditions. Just `while (x || y)` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so in Java, the best way would be

```
while(x || y)
```

If x and y are Booleans. If you are testing conditions,

```
while(x == 5 || y == 3)
```

Comment: Right-O, that got it. Thanks again all!

Comment: I actually used "while( x == true || y == true ){" from above.

Comment: @Nerves82 Ok, just for future reference though, when x and y are booleans, it is preferable to write them as `while( x || y)` This is because if x is true, the statement `x` evaluates to true all on its own. If you write `x == true`, you are asking if `true == true`, which is of course, true.